# Remove the isolated storage key/value pair on Application_Activated in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Application_Deactivated event, I am storing the data into IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings as key/value pair.

In Application_Activated and Application_Closing events, I am removing the data from IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

But when i check the isolated storage settings after removing the data, still the key/value pairs is exists.

I am pretty sure that i have removed the key/value pairs in Application_Activated and Application_Closing. I can see the debug line "deleted" printed.

And I am nowhere saving the data other than Application_Deactivated event.

please help me.. I am not getting where exactly its going wrong. how the data is still exists in isolatedstotage after removing ?

I am removing the data like below:

```
    public void Remove(string token)
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (token != null && store.Contains(token))
        if (store.Remove(token) == true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("deleted after Remove " + token);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Not deleted after Remove " + token);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save settings after removing key.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

Edited : in you case.

```
public void Remove(string token)
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (token != null && store.Contains(token))
        if (store.Remove(token) == true)
        {
            //Save it here : 
            store.save();
            Debug.WriteLine("deleted after Remove " + token);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Not deleted after Remove " + token);
        }

       //Or call it here : 
        store.save();
    }
```